# Inverse image; cut of domain of an increasing function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I want to proof the following set theory exercise (from C. Pinter)

Let $A$ and $B$ be partially ordered classes, and let $f : A → B$ be an increasing function; assume $\vec{f}(A)=B$. Prove that if $(L, U)$ is a cut of $B$, then $(f^{-1}(L), f^{-1}(U))$ is a cut of $A$.

I tried it by contradiction, but it came to nothing. I appreciate tips to proof it

Comment: Is $\vec f$ the range of $f$, so that here $f[A]=B$? And for his definition of cut, do $L$ and $U$ satisfy any other conditions besides $L$ being downward closed, $U$ being upward closed, $L\cap U=\varnothing$, and $L\cup U=B$?

Comment: I actually also said both of those: the first says that $U$ is upward closed, and the second says that $L$ is downward closed. Another pair of terms used for this concept: $L$ is a *down set*, and $U$ is an *up set*.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience let $L'=f^{-1}[L]$ and $U'=f^{-1}[U]$. It’s clear that $$L'\cup U'=f^{-1}[L]\cup f^{-1}[U]=f^{-1}[L\cup U]=f^{-1}[B]=A$$ and that $$L'\cap U'=f^{-1}[L]\cap f^{-1}[U]=f^{-1}[L\cap U]=f^{-1}[\varnothing]=\varnothing\,.$$ Thus, $\{L',U'\}$ is a partition of $A$.

Suppose that $a_0\le a_1\in L'$. Then $f(a_0)\le f(a_1)\in L$, so $f(a_0)\in L$, and therefore $a_0\in L'$, i.e., $L'$ is downward closed. A similar argument shows that if $a_0\le a_1$, and $a_0\in U'$, then $a_1\in U'$, so that $U'$ is upward closed. Thus, $\langle L',U'\rangle$ is a cut in $A$.

Comment: Great answer! In my opinion, the steps $f^{-1}[L \cup U] \subseteq f^{-1}[L] \cup f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[L] \cap f^{-1}[U] \subseteq f^{-1}[L \cap U]$ deserve a comment because they rely on the fact that $\{L,U\}$ is a partition of $B$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: No, function inverses perserve unions and intersections, so those are equalities irrespective of $L$ and $U$.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right. My comment was really silly. I'll delete it.